# Wordpress customize specific site

Tags: html, wordpress

I made a little game using html and new I´m looking to publish it on my wordpress site. There is only on problem though, I don´t know how to add a page in html code. If I add a new Site I can only edit the text and attach pictures, but is there a way to add a complete page under a domain like www.example.com/page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the HTML file to your website's root directory using FTP. If you name it `game.html`, you should be able to open the file by navigating directly to it `www.example.com/game.html`.

Comment: I don´t know why I didn´t think of that myself, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You go to `My Page`. Then there is a submenu `Publish`. Click on the button `Add` next to `Pages`. When you did that, there is that small menu in the middle where you can choose several options such as `header, bold, italics, etc.`. In the top right corner of that menu, there are two options: `Visual | HTML`. Just click on `HTML` and you can add HTML code.